# How do i change all occurrences only in the function in VScode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide

In VSCode i can change all occurrences of a word by selecting a word and using the "change all occurrences" feature.

This feature will select all matching words in the file.
Is there any way I can select all occurrences in a function only and not all over the file?

For example, change all the occurrences of "some_variable" in f1() without changing the ones in f2():

```
f1():
    some_variable = 'meow'
    print(some_variable)
    

f2():
    some_variable = 'bark'
    print(some_variable)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the portion of code you want to search in and Use "Find in Selection" 
 In windows you can use shortcut Alt + L 
[Here is demo for your example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFYG8.png)